# Mysql - Docker: Connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  frontend:
    build: frontend
    container_name: yii-frontend
    ports:
      - 20080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - my-marian-net

  backend:
    build: backend
    container_name: yii-backend
    ports:
      - 21080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - my-marian-net

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql8
    command: --user=root --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_USER=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 6033:3306
    networks: 
      - my-marian-net

networks: 
  my-marian-net:
    driver: bridge
```

I get an error message:

> 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known'

Solutions I have tried:

- Ping from backend and frontend container to mysql8: docker exec -ti yii-frontend ping mysql8 (It works!)
- Manually connect each container to the same network (my-marian-net) docker network connect my-marian-net mysql8 (same for each container)
- I have connected into the mysql container and test connection there, it works.
- I have connected from containers to mysql8 container MySQL service and it works.

So far no luck getting connected. In my code, I am using "db" as hostname since I am using bridge mode.

After trying different solutions, I have isolated the issue to a connection from 
 outside docker, Any suggestion?

I am using macOS Mojave. Docker version 19.03

Comment: you said, `ping mysql8` and it works. Then you didn't try using "mysql8" as hostname instead of "db"?

Comment: @Smankusors in the connection you need to use the name of the service, which is "db". I tried mysql8 just in case, but no luck. The issue seems some problem between my local and the bridge network, it seems no communication there.

Comment: it could be some internal DNS issue with Docker, what is your Docker version? Can you try reboot your computer?

Comment: I am using docker 19.03 in macos Mojave. It could be a dns issue but how to test?

Comment: oh yeah btw, how your yii connect to the DB? The database config? The connection string?

Comment: That part works, If I try to connect from inside yii-backend container to mysql8 container, it works, the issue is when calling the connection from outside the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209974/discussion-between-smankusors-and-eduardo).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simpler than I thought, from outside container "db" service does not exist, so no possibility to get connected.

In the future when I run console commands from local, I will change host in database connection to use localhost instead of "db" or get connected to the container itself and run them from inside.

Thanks to @Smankusors for the help.